# How to change the fields in the syntax?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

`TreeMap <String,Integer> H = new TreeMap <String,Integer>();`

If i use Long at place of Integer it gives the error!

How to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is extremely unclear and cannot answered as is. Please read the [Help Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should also read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). To help people answering your question, learn how to create a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please describe what your problem? It is unclear what is it and you say "If I use Long at place of Long" (?) which does not help at all...

Comment: You are using *raw* generics. Don't. Use e.g. `TreeMap<Long, Long> H = new TreeMap<>();`

Comment: What is the error you're talking about?

Comment: @MauricePerry if use the method `put` for some string and Long, it gives error as `no suitable method found for put(String,int)`.

Comment: @PradhumnPanchal it seems that you're trying to pass an `int`, not a `Long`.

Comment: @MauricePerry question url - https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/n-co-ordinates-pair-practice/.     My  Solution url - http://ide.codingblocks.com/s/52144

Comment: @PradhumnPanchal so I guess the error is on `H.put(S,1);`. Just change it to `H.put(S,1L);`.

Comment: @MauricePerry thanks sir but still giving wrong & TLE

Comment: @PradhumnPanchal what is wrong? what is is doing, and what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace Integer with Long as :

```
TreeMap<String, Long> H = new TreeMap<String, Long>();
```

OR

```
TreeMap<String, Long> H = new TreeMap<>();
```

If we declare like below then we will get Type mismatch: cannot convert from specific Type to Specific Type error.

```
TreeMap<String, Long> H = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Here we will get Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeMap to TreeMap.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> H = new TreeMap<String, Long>();
```

Here we will get Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeMap to TreeMap

Comment: Yes. I would go a step futher and write `Map <String,Long> H = new TreeMap <>();`.